# Is this the right notion of "relatively arithmetical"?

Tags: logic, computability

Say I want to tease out an arithmetical property from the ether: I get it's $\Pi^0_n$ $(\Sigma^0_n)$, and I get some indices for programs that compute structures (their (atomic) diagrams) with that property. So lets say I want to check for a certain property *among those guys*, and I manage to show this is $\Pi^0_m$ $(\Sigma^0_m)$ ***relative*** to this set of indices I was talking about.

Is this new property $\Pi^0_{m + n}$ $(\Sigma^0_{m+n})$ in some absolute sense? If there is already some terminology for this (probably yes) please let me know. Also if necessary please smuggle in the word *complete* where suitable.

Comment: Huh??  What is $\prod_{m+n}^0 \left( \sum_{m+n}^0 \right)$?  What does the *sum* $m+n$ have to do with anything?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The notation $\Pi^0_i/\Sigma^0_i$ in this context is [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).

Comment: That said, I do find the post rather confusingly written. Are you asking what we can say about a set which is (for example) $\Pi^0_m$ relative to a $\Sigma^0_n$ oracle? What you've written is rather vague.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Indeed, $\Pi_i^0 / \Sigma_i^0$ is standard, but I have never seen what BigSocks wrote—$\Pi_i^0 (\Sigma_i^0)$—in any of my books on computability theory.  Do *you* understand it?

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes exactly this.

Comment: it just means wlog $\Pi^0_n$ (so it could also be $\Sigma^0_n$).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have seen that notation before - "$\Gamma_0(\Gamma_1)$" basically means "$\Gamma_0$ relative to a $\Gamma_1$ predicate of the appropriate type" - but actually here I think it's just a parenthetical indicating an alternate option, e.g. "$\Pi^0_n$ (respectively, $\Sigma^0_n$)" ... "$\Pi^0_{m+n}$ (resp. $\Sigma^0_{m+n}$)" and so on.

Comment: yeah the latter

Comment: Oh jeez... that certainly wasn't clear, given (as @NoahSchweber states) there are two alternatives *with very different meanings*.  Why not be clear from the beginning?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Actually it gets a bit worse since even within the first meaning there's a small-but-significant ambiguity (I'm writing an answer up now which will address that).

Comment: right but it's not the first meaning @NoahSchweber . Furthermore, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, everything is basically additive. However, there's a slight catch:

Suppose $A$ is $\Sigma^0_1$ and $B$ has the form $$\{x: \exists y\varphi(x,y)\},$$ where $\varphi$ is a formula with only bounded quantifiers in which $A$ gets used as a unary predicate symbol. Now there are two plausible guesses for the complexity of $B$, namely $\Sigma^0_1$ (since everything is existential) or $\Sigma^0_2$ (since there are two quantifiers involved).

The answer depends on **how** the unary predicate corresponding to $A$ gets used in $\varphi$. If it occurs only positively, then $B$ is $\Sigma^0_1$; otherwise, however, $B$ is merely guaranteed to be $\Sigma^0_2$. Indeed you can show that the following are equivalent for a set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$:

- $X$ is $\Sigma^0_2$.
- $X$ is c.e. relative to some co-c.e. oracle.
- $X$ is c.e. relative to some c.e. oracle.

The point is that in a Turing reduction, both positive *and* negative information about the oracle is used (contrast this with enumeration reductions).

This indicates a dangerous ambiguity with phrases like "$\Sigma^0_m$-over-$\Sigma^0_k$" - we need to be careful about whether the inner predicate occurs positively or both positively and negatively. From what you've described, the latter is the correct interpretation. We then have pretty much what one should expect, e.g. **in this sense** $\Sigma^0_m$-over-$\Sigma^0_n$ is $\Sigma^0_m$-over-$\Pi^0_n$ is $\Sigma^0_{m+n}$. But in other contexts we might want to pay attention to finer restrictions and have "positivity" conditions involved in the way the inner predicate gets used.

However, basically everything else gets incredibly messy. For example:

- Suppose $X$ is a high c.e. set, $X\le_m Y$, and $Y$ is "$\Pi^0_1$-complete-over-$X$." Then $X$ is not $\Sigma^0_1$ complete but $Y$ is $\Pi^0_2$-complete.
- That "$X\le_mY$" bit is important: we can have e.g. a c.e. set $X$ and a set $Y$ such that $Y$ is "c.e.-over-$X$" but $Y$ doesn't compute $X$!

So folding in e.g. completeness questions makes things very fiddly.

Comment: This is such a well thought out answer; thank you. Is this in Soare somewhere? Otherwise do you know where I could read more? Also your two last bullets are completely mystifying me. Could you say more? An example? Also if at each step of the $\Sigma^0_n$-over-$\Sigma^0_m$ business I can get completeness, does this help matters? Or is it kind of a "useless" thing to prove?

Comment: @BigSocks You would have to pose your question re: completeness much more precisely for me to be able to say anything. The most I can say is that if at each step we're appropriately complete **and** $m$-above everything so far, then we retain completeness. But that's very limited. As to where it can be found, I think it's in Soare in the exercises somewhere but I don't have my copy on hand.

Comment: Yeah I just thought of taking a set $X$ which I'd show was $\Sigma^0_n$ complete within some class of computable structures, and then talk about $Y$ that was $\Sigma^0_m$ complete with respect to the class of computable structures you get from $X$. But I can see now that being $m$-above $X$ is somehow also important...