# More on relative computability in this question

Tags: logic, computability

I was thinking about this question:

[Is this the right notion of "relatively arithmetical"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036126/is-this-the-right-notion-of-relatively-arithmetical/4036233?noredirect=1#comment8334623_4036233)

and I was wondering what would happen if we took 2 properties, one $\Pi^0_n$ and one $\Sigma^0_m$, and identified classes of structures in the following way:  you have one situation checking for the first property and then the second, while, separately, you check for the second and then the first.

According to the answer, assuming we use the information from each oracle positively *and* negatively, we get a $\Sigma^0_{m+n}$-complete set in the first situation, but a $\Pi^0_{m+n}$-complete set in the second situation.

This seems intuitively troubling. How could checking for the same 2 properties in different orders yield different complexities?

EDIT: It is not true that “According to the answer...” one gets what i claimed, but it is interesting to wonder nonetheless.

Comment: "According to the answer ... we get a $\Sigma^0_{m+n}$-complete set in the first situation, but a $\Pi^0_{m+n}$-complete set in the second situation." I was very careful to say that you **don't** in general get completeness! To quote my answer: "However, basically everything else gets incredibly messy.  ... [F]olding in e.g. completeness questions makes things very fiddly." All you're getting is an **upper** bound. The mention of type of information used was to explain why a better upper bound is not guaranteed in general.

Comment: (Separately, a minor point: talking about structures in this context isn't a great idea at first. Structures add a level of complexity, since now we need to look at only isomorphism-closed classes and isomorphism is in general highly complicated. The questions you're asking are just about arithmetical sets of natural numbers.)

Comment: Right so we have to do a reduction of the relevant complexity class to identification of the (isomorphism class of) the problem? And only *then* we can get completeness? Also I appreciate the precision in language, as well as the note on structures.

Comment: And in this case should we expect one of the two reductions to be impossible?

Comment: Yes - since the arithmetical hierarchy doesn't collapse, no set can be $\Pi^0_m$-complete and $\Sigma^0_n$-complete simultaneously for any $m,n$.

Comment: Right, so in case the first scenario is the one that admits reduction, we reduce $\Sigma^0_m$ to identifying (isomorphism classes) of the structure with said property *that had the $\Pi^0_n$ property*, and we get $\Sigma^0_{m+n}$-completeness?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120350/discussion-between-bigsocks-and-noah-schweber).